# print rows if string match found in csv file pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote the following code for the subject task.
I think the loop is running fine but the print command is not showing any output.
Can you please see and help me fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv') # read 1st file to get strings from a column 
da = pd.read_csv("file2.csv",encoding = 'unicode_escape') #read 2nd file to search the string in
a =393
b = 0
c = 712
d = 0
while b<a: 
    D = df.iloc[b,0] # get string in bth row of 1st column of 1st file
    DD = da.iloc[d,0] # get string in dth row of 1st column of 2nd file
    while d<c:
        if D == DD: # match two strings 
            print(da.iloc[0,:]) # if matched then print entire row from 2nd file
            d += 1
    b += 1
```

Comment: do you mean full row match with other file's row , and print matched row of file?

Comment: no, just get all strings in a selected column in file 1 and match them with row entries in the selected column in file 2 and then print the full row from file 2 to a new csv file 3.